# How do firebase online DB work when there is no update?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Scenario 1 - Precondition - Keepsynced (false) and setPersistenceEnabled(true)

**1.** I have a online firebase DB (Real time DB) setup.

**2.** App is launched for 1st time, it will get all the db data and store local.

**3.** Close the app and launch after 2 hours.

**4.** Question - Will the app download all the DB data from online even when there is no update in online DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

It means that you'll be able to query your the database even if your users go offline. This is happening because Firebase creates a local copy of your database on user's device. To answer your question:

> Question - Will the app download all the DB data from online even when there is no update in online DB ?

No! If there is no update, you'll read the data that is coming from cache.